# Dagster PySpark not running on EMR

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr, dagster

I am trying to build an pipeline in Dagster which does the following:

1. Launch an EMR cluster using the [EmrJobRunner](https://docs.dagster.io/_modules/dagster_aws/emr/emr#EmrJobRunner) class, by using its
   run_job_flow function.
2. Add one or more steps to that cluster to process data in PySpark by
   using the [emr_pyspark_step_launcher](https://docs.dagster.io/_modules/dagster_aws/emr/pyspark_step_launcher#emr_pyspark_step_launcher) resource.
3. Shut down the cluster once all steps are finished.

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.dagster.io/integrations/spark#submitting-pyspark-ops-on-emr) first, which assumes that you have an EMR cluster running and you hard code the EMR cluster ID as part of the Job specification. This way worked, as I could see my steps being run on EMR. However, when I try to automate the process I noticed that PySpark was running locally and not on EMR. I tried to wrap the emr_pyspark_step_launcher as a Resource which sets the cluster ID as part of the pipeline. The cluster ID can be obtained by using a function in the EmrJobRunner class which returns a cluster ID when providing a cluster name. I am trying to dynamically add the cluster ID during the job after launching the cluster but this isn't working as expected.

This is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
from pathlib import Path
from dagster_aws.emr import emr_pyspark_step_launcher
from dagster_aws.emr.emr import EmrJobRunner
from dagster_aws.s3 import s3_resource
from dagster_pyspark import pyspark_resource
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from transformations import execute_transformation
from dagster import IOManager, graph, io_manager, op, resource, In, Nothing, Out
from utils.configs import get_emr_cluster_config
import logging


class ParquetIOManager(IOManager):
    def _get_path(self, context):
        return "/".join(
            [
                context.resource_config["path_prefix"],
                context.run_id,
                context.step_key,
                context.name,
            ]
        )

    def handle_output(self, context, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
            obj.write.parquet(self._get_path(context))
        # return obj

    def load_input(self, context):
        spark = context.resources.pyspark.spark_session
        return spark.read.parquet(self._get_path(context.upstream_output))


@io_manager(required_resource_keys={"pyspark"}, config_schema={"path_prefix": str})
def parquet_io_manager():
    return ParquetIOManager()


@resource
def emr_job_runner(init_context):
    return EmrJobRunner(region="eu-central-1")


@resource(
    config_schema={"cluster_name": str}, required_resource_keys={"emr_job_runner"}
)
def my_pyspark_step_launcher(init_context):
    cluster_id = init_context.resources.emr_job_runner.cluster_id_from_name(
        cluster_name=init_context.resource_config["cluster_name"]
    )
    init_context.log.info(f"CLUSTER ID during resource initilization: {cluster_id}")

    return emr_pyspark_step_launcher.configured(
        {
            "cluster_id": cluster_id,
            "local_pipeline_package_path": str(Path(__file__).parent.parent),
            "deploy_local_pipeline_package": True,
            "region_name": "eu-central-1",
            "staging_bucket": "EMR_STAGING_BUCKET",
            "wait_for_logs": True,
        }
    )
    

def launch_cluster(emr: EmrJobRunner, log: logging.Logger, emr_config: dict) -> None:
    emr_config = get_emr_cluster_config(
        release_label=emr_config["emr_release_label"],
        cluster_name=emr_config["cluster_name"],
        master_node_instance_type=emr_config["master_node_instance_type"],
        worker_node_instance_type=emr_config["worker_node_instance_type"],
        worker_node_instance_count=emr_config["worker_node_instance_count"],
        ec2_subnet_id=emr_config["ec2_subnet_id"],
        bid_price=emr_config["worker_node_spot_bid_price"],
    )

    return emr.run_job_flow(log=log, cluster_config=emr_config)


@op(
    config_schema={
        "emr_release_label": str,
        "cluster_name": str,
        "master_node_instance_type": str,
        "worker_node_instance_type": str,
        "worker_node_instance_count": int,
        "ec2_subnet_id": str,
        "worker_node_spot_bid_price": str,
    },
    required_resource_keys={"emr_job_runner"},
    out=Out(Nothing),
)
def launch_emr_cluster(context) -> None:
    op_config = context.op_config

    cluster_id = launch_cluster(
        emr=context.resources.emr_job_runner, log=context.log, emr_config=op_config
    )

    context.log.info(f"CLUSTER ID: {cluster_id}")


@op(
    ins={"start": In(Nothing)},
    required_resource_keys={"pyspark", "pyspark_step_launcher"},
)
def get_dataframe(context) -> DataFrame:
    return execute_transformation(spark_session=context.resources.pyspark.spark_session)


@graph
def make_and_filter_data():
    get_dataframe(launch_emr_cluster())


run_data_emr = make_and_filter_data.to_job(
    name="prod",
    resource_defs={
        "pyspark_step_launcher": my_pyspark_step_launcher,
        "pyspark": pyspark_resource,
        "s3": s3_resource.configured({"region_name": "eu-central-1"}),
        "io_manager": parquet_io_manager.configured(
            {"path_prefix": "s3://EMR_STEP_OUTPUT"}
        ),
        "emr_job_runner": emr_job_runner,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky because resources are initialized for every op, and are initialized prior to the op starting. So you can't modify / pass values from an op to a resource initialization. In this particular case, I think what you might want to try is doing the cluster initialization in the step launcher resource definition - that way you have access to the cluster ID at the time that the step launcher is being initialized. Something like this:

```py
@resource
def emr_job_runner(init_context):
    return EmrJobRunner(region="eu-central-1")
    

def launch_cluster(emr: EmrJobRunner, log: logging.Logger, emr_config: dict) -> None:
    emr_config = get_emr_cluster_config(
        release_label=emr_config["emr_release_label"],
        cluster_name=emr_config["cluster_name"],
        master_node_instance_type=emr_config["master_node_instance_type"],
        worker_node_instance_type=emr_config["worker_node_instance_type"],
        worker_node_instance_count=emr_config["worker_node_instance_count"],
        ec2_subnet_id=emr_config["ec2_subnet_id"],
        bid_price=emr_config["worker_node_spot_bid_price"],
    )

    return emr.run_job_flow(log=log, cluster_config=emr_config)

@resource(config_schema={
        "emr_release_label": str,
        "cluster_name": str,
        "master_node_instance_type": str,
        "worker_node_instance_type": str,
        "worker_node_instance_count": int,
        "ec2_subnet_id": str,
        "worker_node_spot_bid_price": str,
    },
    required_resource_keys={"emr_job_runner"})
def cluster_launcher(init_context):
    config = init_context.resource_config

    # TODO: handle if cluster already exists, as this resource will be initialized for each op / resource
    # that requires it
    cluster_id = launch_cluster(
        emr=context.resources.emr_job_runner, log=context.log, emr_config=config
    )

    context.log.info(f"CLUSTER ID: {cluster_id}")
    return cluster_id


@resource(
    config_schema={"cluster_name": str}, required_resource_keys={"emr_job_runner", "cluster_launcher"}
)
def my_pyspark_step_launcher(init_context):
    cluster_id = init_context.resources.cluster_launcher
    init_context.log.info(f"CLUSTER ID during resource initilization: {cluster_id}")

    return emr_pyspark_step_launcher.configured(
        {
            "cluster_id": cluster_id,
            "local_pipeline_package_path": str(Path(__file__).parent.parent),
            "deploy_local_pipeline_package": True,
            "region_name": "eu-central-1",
            "staging_bucket": "EMR_STAGING_BUCKET",
            "wait_for_logs": True,
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I appreciate your help :) Unfortunately I am still getting the same issue.  The cluster is deployed and the correct ID is logged, but PySpark is trying to run locally instead of deploying the step to EMR. I am not sure why this happens because the code should initialize the cluster ID in the same way it does in this tutorial: https://docs.dagster.io/integrations/spark#submitting-pyspark-ops-on-emr

Another option might be to use the EmrJobRunner itself to launch steps onto EMR and write my Spark transformations appropriately.